# Use complex substitution to evaluate integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Use the substitution $z = e^{i\theta}$ to evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\sin(\theta)-2}$$

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Pointing:  $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = \cos \theta + \mathrm{i} \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 4):

Combine the highlights of Mary Star's and Dr. MV's answers.

Substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sin(\theta)-2}
&=\oint\overbrace{\frac{2i}{z-\frac1z-4i}}^{\frac1{\sin(\theta)-2}}\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}\ \ \ \ }^{\mathrm{d}\theta}\\
&=\oint\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}z}{z^2-4iz-1}\\
&=\oint\frac1{i\sqrt3}\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac1{z-i\left(2+\sqrt3\right)}}-\color{#00A000}{\frac1{z-i\left(2-\sqrt3\right)}}\right)\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{i\sqrt3}(\color{#C00000}{0}-\color{#00A000}{1})\\[3pt]
&=-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}
\end{align}
$$
where $i\left(2+\sqrt3\right)$ is outside the unit circle and $\frac1{z-i\left(2-\sqrt3\right)}$ has a residue of $1$.

Comment: How did you compute that residue?

Comment: the residue of $f$ at $z=\alpha$ is the coefficient of $\frac1{z-\alpha}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$ at $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ so that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin \theta -2}\,d\theta &=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{2}{\left(z-i(2+\sqrt 3)\right)\left(z-i(2-\sqrt 3)\right)}\,dz \tag 1\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{2}{-i2\sqrt 3)}\right) \tag 2\\\\
&=-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we invoked the Residue Theorem.

Comment: You seem to be missing a minus sign (the integrand is negative everywhere)

Comment: How did you figure the domain would be $|z|=1$?

Comment: @robjon Rob.  Thanks for the catch.  +1 when one is careless and overlooks the easy things while doind lots of arithmetic in one's head, ... well you get the point.  Edited.  - Mark

Comment: @yotengounlcd For $z=e^{i\theta}$, $|z|=1$ and as $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, the entire unit circle is traced.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta +i \sin \theta$$ 
$$e^{-i\theta}=\cos \theta -i \sin \theta$$

So $$\sin \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i \theta}}{2i}\Rightarrow \sin \theta=i\frac{e^{-i\theta}-e^{i \theta}}{2}=i\frac{z^{-1}-z}{2}$$